when add firebase to myflutter project and run it project build and run but force close
my main code and i fully impelement firebase step by step
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'features/feature_authentication/presentation/screen/authentication_page.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

onCreate() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
  );
}
Future<void> main() async {


  runApp(const AuthenticationFlowScreen());
}


E/AndroidRuntime(13476): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13476): Process: com.tordodigi.footballpd, PID: 13476
E/AndroidRuntime(13476): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tordodigi.footballpd/com.tordodigi.footballpd.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tordodigi.footballpd.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~tfneJCFtdgmG0C6Z6QBbZQ==/com.tordodigi.footballpd-J99fzEFKxupfZmWyQqqrmQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~tfneJCFtdgmG0C6Z6QBbZQ==/com.tordodigi.footballpd-J99fzEFKxupfZmWyQqqrmQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~tfneJCFtdgmG0C6Z6QBbZQ==/com.tordodigi.footballpd-J99fzEFKxupfZmWyQqqrmQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tordodigi.footballpd.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~tfneJCFtdgmG0C6Z6QBbZQ==/com.tordodigi.footballpd-J99fzEFKxupfZmWyQqqrmQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~tfneJCFtdgmG0C6Z6QBbZQ==/com.tordodigi.footballpd-J99fzEFKxupfZmWyQqqrmQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~tfneJCFtdgmG0C6Z6QBbZQ==/com.tordodigi.footballpd-J99fzEFKxupfZmWyQqqrmQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
E/AndroidRuntime(13476):    ... 11 more

Do check this post out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046199/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-in-flutter
